# can’t connect to overpass

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I can’t connect to overpass!

```
import osmnx as ox
ox.plot_graph(ox.graph_from_place(‘Modena, Italy’))
```

gives:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='overpass-api.de', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/interpreter (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

Also noticed that osmnx gets more nodes that openstreetmap per box – how can this happen ?
thnks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Overpass API was probably down. I just tested now and was able to connect without a problem. I'd suggest trying again.